# Integrate PHPMailer in Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, phpmailer

I have written a PHP app that sends email for user validation with PHPMailer. Locally everything works like a charm, and I would like to now deploy it in Prod on Heroku and I am looking for guidance on how to integrate PHPMailer there. Unfortunately, I couldn't find very clear material about it.
I understand that Heroku uses composer and that I may need to edit composer.json. There is currently no composer.json in my deployed app on Heroku.
Should I simply create it from scratch?
If so, should I require only PHPMailer or is there anything else that I should include?

Sorry for the dumb questions, I am new to Heroku and I just want to make sure I don't compromise the deployment since it's working fine, and all I need to do is integrate the mail part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your own computer, with composer installed, run this in the root directory of your project:

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

That will create a `composer.json` file, a `composer.lock` file, and a `vendor` folder containing composer utilities (such as `autoload.php`) and PHPMailer's files. Normally you'd add the two composer files to your git repo, but not the `vendor` folder.

That should mean you can run your project locally. When it comes to transferring it to Heroku, I would expect you to upload everything *except* the `vendor` folder, and Heroku will spot the two composer files and use them to install exactly the same files on your server.

If Heroku *doesn't* install things for you, you can upload the `vendor` folder too, but this is not recommended.

When I say "upload" I expect that you would normally allow Heroku to access a git repository with your code in and have it pull the files from there (and perhaps automatically pull changes when you push to your repo), rather than you manually uploading.

Comment: Hello @Synchro,

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I still have some problems 1) I managed to deploy PHPMailer on Heroku, but it doesn't tell me where the files are located so I don't know what to "require" on my PHP file. I tried the same path as I have locally (/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/...) but I get "Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/server.php on line 15". How do I know where these files are on Heroku? 2) If I leave composer.json and composer.lock in the folder, the extension keep on being downloaded and installed at every subsequent git push. Should I remove them?

Comment: No, leave them there. You don’t need to know where the PHPMailer files are, only where the composer autoloader is, usually `vendor/autoload.php` relative to your project root. If Heroku allows yo roll back to older versions, it’s normal to have it install every time.

Comment: Thanks @Synchro, your comment greatly helped. In addition to what you said, I modified my project in order to have a document root and a web root in the public/ subdirectory. I additionally added a .user.ini. file in the document root with the following content include_path=".:/vendor/". In my php file which requires PHPMailer I added the following use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP; require '../vendor/autoload.php'; Finally it all works!

Comment: That all sounds right, glad it worked out! Composer makes things much simpler in many ways, but it can be tricky to get started.